# Visual SVN and Bug Tracking Integrated

Tags: svn, debugging, integration, visualsvn

So I have a perfectively working VisualSVN that me and my other 2 team members use (tiny team). The problem is at the moment that we use an excel spreadsheet to really maintain our bugs.

We have said for ages "get around to installing some bug tracking software" - never had the time. So today, biting the bullet.

What is the best software to integrate with VisualSVN and anyone got any instrucions for Vista etc?

Thanks

Comment: This question should probably be community wiki, as there is no definite "best" bug tracking software.

Answer (score 6):

Consider using [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). It integrates nicely with Subversion, provides bug tracking, a wiki and a bunch of other nice features. And it's free. My favorite feature is that it gives you a nice timeline view that shows a chronological list of everything that has happened in a time period, from bug status changes to subversion commits. It also has a slick web-based Subversion repository viewer. The bug tracker isn't the most advanced in the world, but coming from a spreadsheet, I'm sure it will have everything you would want and more.

Comment: you can also look into adding the agilo plugin that gives trac a bit more power :)
I also like you can download diff between revision for a whole directory.

Answer (score 4):

Integration with VisualSVN isn't much of an issue. Most tracking software looks for entries in the log message, entries like:

Fixes #443

We used [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) with a lot of success at my last place. It's like trac, but multi-project.
We made use of the bugtraq properties to highlight and provide links to the bugs from within tortoisesvn.

Answer (score 2):

We're using [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) . It seems to integrate fairly nicely with SVN. You can link in your bug tracking number with a checkin and Jira will give you a list of the changes made for that bug etc. I personally preferred Fogbugs from a usability perspective - especially if customers or support staff are going to be using the bug tracking system. I was overruled though and we went with Jira because it is a far more powerful system for engineers.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/). Not free, but affordable for small teams, and it integrates nicely with SVN. Installation and configuration is a breeze, compared to some other open-source bug trackers.

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion. you gotta pay though - there is far too many free solns out there to justify paying :)

Comment: Most free solutions aren't nearly as easy to use and setup as FogBugz. Time is money also, so if you save a lot of time setting it up, you've paid for the modest license fee many times over.

Comment: @andy
are you getting paid for your time and effort?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Artifacts](http://www.versioned.com/artifacts/visual-studio/overview/). Integrates with Visual Studio, works with Subversion and fits small team very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitnami products, they are present a lot of open source software will all needs, for example svn, apache, ruby and so on. also you can download vmware images that you can run on virtual machines. and for bug tracking I suggest bitnami redmine that is a very nice project management system with bug tracking, Wiki, file attachment, document, and svn integration. you can download a installer that Install redmine, apache and all pre needs on your system.
please visit : http://bitnami.org/

and text of bitnami's site

> Refreshingly simple!
>
> Free, easy to setup wikis, blogs, forums and many other web applications that you can run locally or in the cloud. BitNami makes deploying server software a simple and enjoyable process.

Answer (score 0):

[trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is free and integrates easily with svn

I'd suggest you actually outsource the hosting to some other services - they will host them for you and take care of backing up, get to it from anywhere in the world, etc.  Unless of course you have that all taken care of and don;t mind managing it yourselves.